# How do I use restsharp to read a Json array

Tags: json, deserialization, restsharp

I need to read the following piece of code using RestSharp. My problem is how to get the array in the proper structure. How do I need to setup the class that will contain the object to make this work properly?

I would like to deserialize the object "0" and "1" in a List of type AcUserInfo.

Thanks a lot.
Andrea

```
{
   "0":{
      "id":"2",
      "subscriberid":"2",
      "cdate":"2012-09-28 16:49:06",
      "sdate":"2012-09-28 16:49:06",
      "first_name":"Al",
      "last_name":"",
      "email":"test@verizon.net"
   },
   "1":{
      "id":"29",
      "subscriberid":"29",
      "cdate":"2012-10-02 15:08:29",
      "sdate":"2012-10-02 15:08:29",
      "first_name":"Mark",
      "last_name":"",
      "email":"test2@verizon.net"
   },
   "result_code":1,
   "result_message":"Success: Something is returned",
   "result_output":"json"
}
```

Here's the class I've created:

```
public class SubscriberList {
    public int result_code { get; set; }
    public string result_message { get; set; }
    public string result_output { get; set; }
    public List<AcUserInfo> row { get; set; }

    SubscriberList(){
        row = new List<AcUserInfo>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data does not contain an array, and therefore cannot be deserialized to a List<>.

Either convert your JSON to something like this:

```
{
  [{
  "id":"2",
  "subscriberid":"2",
  "cdate":"2012-09-28 16:49:06",
  "sdate":"2012-09-28 16:49:06",
  "first_name":"Al",
  "last_name":"",
  "email":"test@verizon.net"
  },
  {
  "id":"29",
  "subscriberid":"29",
  "cdate":"2012-10-02 15:08:29",
  "sdate":"2012-10-02 15:08:29",
  "first_name":"Mark",
  "last_name":"",
  "email":"test2@verizon.net"
  }],
  "result_code":1,
  "result_message":"Success: Something is returned",
  "result_output":"json"
}
```

Or if you always only have the "0" & "1" element then change your SubscriberList class to match it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The items were returned that way by ActiveCampaign. I managed to fix my problem returning the items as xml. Thanks.